# Spring controller : How to deserialize a json into a Map<Object, Object>

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, hashmap

I use Unity to send JSON to a Spring server. However, I don't know how to deserialize such a complex object.
What would be the cleanest way to do this ?

I have these 3 classes :

```
public class Garden {
    private Integer width;
    private Integer height;
    private Map<Position, Sprite> objects;

    public Garden(Integer width, Integer height, Map<Position, Sprite> objects) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    /* getters and setters */
}
```

```
public class Position {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Position(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    /* getters and setters */
}
```

```
public class Sprite {
    private String name;
    private Boolean mirrored;
    private Integer size;

    public Sprite(String name, Boolean mirrored, Integer size) {
        this.name = name;
        this.mirrored = mirrored;
        this.size = size;
    }

    /* getters and setters */
}
```

The PostMapping method inside the controller :

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Garden> postGarden(Garden garden) {
   /* Doing things */
}
```

And the JSON is in this format

```
{
   "objects":{
      "(1, 1)":{
         "name":"Box",
         "size":1,
         "mirrored":false
      },
      "(5, 7)":{
         "name":"Water",
         "size":1,
         "mirrored":false
      }
   },
   "width":10,
   "height":10
}
```

Here, only the width and height are successfully transmitted, but the HashMap is empty.

Would you have any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json's `objects` are `Map<String, Sprite>` while yours is `Map<Position, Sprite>`

Json deserializer cannot automatically convert `String` to `Position`.

You either provide custom converter for `String->Position` for you JSON library (consult the docs for you library) or you can **try** trick JSON library

```
public class Garden {
    private Integer width;
    private Integer height;
    private Map<Position, Sprite> objects;

    public Garden(Integer width, Integer height, Map<Position, Sprite> objects) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    public Map<Position, Sprite> getObjects() { return objects; }

    public void setObjects(Map<Object, Sprite> objects) { 
      this.objects = new HashMap<>(); 
      for (Map.Entry e : objects.entrySet()) {
         Object key = e.getKey();
         Sprite sprite = e.getValue();
         if (key instanceof String) {
           Position position = convertToPosition(key);
           this.objects.put(position, sprite);
         } else if (key instanceof Position){
           this.objects.put((Position)key, sprite);
         } else {
           throw new IllegaStateException(key);
         }
      }
   }

}
```

---

However, better would be to change `Garden` object structure

```
public class SpriteAtPosition {
    private Position position;
    private Sprite sprite;
    ...
}

public class Garden {
    private Integer width;
    private Integer height;
    private List<SpriteAtPosition> sprites;

    public Garden(Integer width, Integer height, List<SpriteAtPosition> sprites) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.sprites = sprites;
    }
```

so Json would be

```
{
   "objects":[
    {
      "position": {
        "x": 1,
        "y": 1,
      },
      "sprite": {
         "name":"Box",
         "size":1,
         "mirrored":false
      }
    },
    {
      "position": {
        "x": 5,
        "y": 7,
      },
      "sprite": {
         "name":"Water",
         "size":1,
         "mirrored":false
      }
    }
   ],
   "width":10,
   "height":10
}
```

Comment: Your second solution worked for me
I just had to also add empty constructors in each class, and it was done.
Thank you very much !